# Cypress loop only visits the first item in the list

Tags: cypress

I'm having trouble recreating this test.

Problem:

It seems that Cypress is only visiting one link from this list whilst looping over each item.

Notes:

- I added the length check to make sure that the array of nodes is the correct size
- The code within each seems to work fine, since the test runner navigates to the first link
- I was looking into the `.next()` methods, but that returns the next DOM nodes. Still not clear if that might be the issues here
- seems like there's no iterator within the `each()` method

Test Case

```
GIVEN a personal website
WHEN when I navigate to the  /blog page
THEN Cypress find the list of blog posts
AND  checks the number of total posts
THEN Cypress loops over those list items
THEN Cypress collects the href
THEN Cypress visits that page
THEN Cypress checks that href includes 'posts'
AND  wait 1s
```

Test Code

```js
describe("Visual regression on /posts/{id}", () => {
  sizes.forEach((size) => {
    it(`Should match screenshot, when '${size}' resolution'`, () => {
      cy.visit("/blog")
      cy.get("ul > li > a")
        .should("have.length", 9)
        .each((element) => {
          cy.wrap(element)
            .invoke("attr", "href")
            .then((href) => {
              cy.visit(href);
            });
          cy.wrap(element)
            .should("have.attr", "href")
            .and("include", "posts"  
          cy.wait(1000);
        });
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution

```js
   cy.visit("/blog");
      cy.get("ul > li > a").should("have.length", 9);
      cy.get("ul > li > a").each(($element) => {
        cy.wrap($element)
          .invoke("attr", "href")
          .then((href) => {
            cy.wrap(href).should("exist")
            cy.visit(href);
            cy.wait(2000);
          });
      });
```

I seems like the block below is letting Cypress loose track of the current element.

```
 .should("have.length", 9)
```

Once I split out the rules of the test, I'm no longer seeing any issues and Cypress is correctly navigating through all the pages I need.